# Can't load i2c_dev module on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, kernel-module

After extensive online research in vain, I am turning to you for help.
My original problem was that my headphone jack stops working on Ubuntu 18.04 when my computer enters sleep-mode or reboots.

To solve this I used this excellent explanation: [Headphone jack stops working after suspend / reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/1047666/headphone-jack-stops-working-after-suspend-reboot)

However, I have encountered difficulties loading the two required i2c modules.
For the first one, i2c_i801, I could solve the problem by removing it from the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.

But then I can't manage to load i2c_dev. I couldn't even locate it using the commands:

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko'
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko*'
```

Would anyone have a solution to this, either by importing somehow the i2c_dev module, or maybe by suggesting a modification to the python script?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Why are you trying to find a filename with `'*.ko*'`?

Comment: At some point I had such a hard time finding the i2c_dev module I wanted to check if it was installed at all. And I found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184877/how-to-list-all-loadable-kernel-modules) that this command would show all loadable modules (which usually have a '.ko' extension), including compressed files. I couldn't find i2c_dev with this method though.